Getting Query Parameter before props in VueJS
I just want one help. Here I have AccountAdmin.vue file is there. In that file, I am requesting parameter from router.push. I got parameter in URL, but problem is that in props, parameter not set first when I load the tab-content. First the props are called and then created() is called. So, I can get parameter from query in myParam, but I need those parameters before props are called. Is there anyway to for this?
AccountAdmin.vue
function expandView(myParam1) {  
if(myParam1 !== ''){  
return 'combine';  
}  
return 'nonCombine';

export default {  
name: 'accounts-admin',  
created() {  
if(this. $route.query.myParam ) {  
const myParam1 = this. $route.query.myParam;  
}  
else{  
console. log('parameter not available');  
}

props: {  
currentTabIndex: {  
type: String, default) {  
let myParam1 = ‘’;  
if(myParam1! =='') {  
myParam1 = this. $route.query.myParam;  
return expandView(myParam1);  
｝  
else{  
return  
'nonCombine';  
｝  
},  
}

Editfile.vue
handLeSubmitCallback({error}) {  
this $router•push({path: '/administration', query: { myParam:’abc’}});

I can get parameter from query in myParam, but I need those parameters before props are called. Is there anyway to do for this?

Usually you react to the changes rather than hack the order or it with reactive conditionals.

This means that currentTabIndex shouldn't be a prop but reactive data. Also see https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props#Function-mode , prop mapping needs to be done at route level rather than component
